# Button at the bottom of the ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have button inside ScrollView

I have put the button inside a scrollview because sometimes contents exceed screen size, in that case I want the button to be at the end of the content
but I want to the button to be on the bottom of the screen when the contents do not exceed screen size

This is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.asmgx.test21.app.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/vsvContents"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Hello..." />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/btnDetOrg"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Move `Button` Outside `ScrollView` or Used `FrameLayout`

Comment: if i moved it outside the ScrollView and the content were too big it will not go under the content it will remain at the end of the screen. my problem is only when the content does not exceed the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add blank view just before button and set its weight 1.

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

hope this will solve your issue.